# I want to calculate completion percentage through SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have scenario where I want to get the percentage of completion.

I have two columns and have to calculate third.

```
 vCompletedTasks | vTotalTasks | vPercentageCompleted

  63               66
  55               70
  35               50
  24               48                 50%
```

I need to write a query which calculates third column, which is percentage.

Comment: It would be `((vCompletedTasks * 100) / vTotalTasks) as ThirdColumn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select vCompletedTasks,vTotalTasks,convert(varchar(2),

((vCompletedTasks * 100) / vTotalTasks))+'%' as vPercentageCompleted

from TableName
```

Comment: Thanks appreciate your response :)

Comment: `convert()` function, in Oracle, has  different purpose. Simply put, it cannot be used to convert a value to a specific data type, and `+` operator, in Oracle, cannot be used for "strings" concatenation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26669507/i-have-to-write-a-very-interesting-query-which-calculates-null-values-and-rows-w?noredirect=1#comment41939760_26669507

Comment: if you guys can help to resolve the above one  as well ... Thanks